# Are there any 3D printer boards or expansions that support more than 3 thermistors?

Tags: electronics, temperature, thermistor, part-identification

A long time ago, I went through the experience of adding extra [thermistors](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/10891/weird-temperature-reading-using-thermistor-on-mks-gen-l-v1-0-aux-2-analog-pins) to my 3D printer board. Ultimately, I did get it to work, but it resulted in extra wiring and was not as clean as I would like.

I was wondering if there are any ready-made 3D printer boards that support adding extra thermistors. I need 5 thermistors for a large 3D printer with a long heated bed. I need the thermistors to measure the temperature of an extruder, the chamber (in 1-2 spots), and 2-3 spots along the bed.

Since I am looking for a new 3D printer board anyway, are there any boards that support adding extra thermistors using a premade PCB or that come with specific JST connectors for up to 5 thermistors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Generally, it will be the boards with lots of steppers (or rather stepstick sockets) which also support lots of heaters/thermistors. For example the BTT Octopus Pro has 4 hotend heater ports, heated bed terminals with dedicated bed power supply, and 5 thermistor ports TB/T0/T1/T2/T3. I suspect other 8-stepper boards are similar, though I haven't checked.

If you'll be using Klipper, though, there's no need for lots of ports on the same board. You can use cheap RAMPS boards or old Creality boards or whatever and connect as many as you like to the Klipper host for it to control in sync.